# What are minerals (other than zinc) that the human body cannot store

Tags: nutrition

It is known that zinc is an essential mineral that the body cannot store.

What are other minerals, especially metals, that the body cannot store?

(other than water-soluble vitamins such as vitamin B and C)

Sincere thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Essential "minerals", i.e., metal cations are magnesium, zinc, iron, potassium, sodium, manganese, molybdenum, selenium, cobalt, copper and even calcium, as we lose a tiny amount of it through urine and sweat. They are all "stored" in some way, but only temporally, so some amount has to be taken up daily. It would show only weeks later, however, if you have a deficiency.

Wikipedia adds phosphorus and iodine but they are not metals.